# Need and Supply Python Algorithm

Tags: python, sql, while-loop

I'm working on an allocation project moving from SQL to Python since I think this will be best dealt with Python. So I have 2 tables below. The first NEED TABLE is where I have the needed items per partner, per store and I've ranked them based on the amount they need with **the goal to supply the stores with the most need first.** The second table is where I have the number of supply available.

The third output table is my goal output for the python code. How do I write a short while code loop for this on python to get the output table? (considering there's a thousands of Partner IDs and ITEM_ID). I was thinking of while syntax but if you have other suggestions feel free!

**NEED_TBL**

| PARTNER_ID | ITEM_ID | STORE | NEED | NEED_RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID32 | 621 | 57 | 1 |
| 1 | ID32 | 321 | 9 | 2 |
| 1 | ID32 | 315 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | ID32 | 732 | 1 | 4 |
| 2 | ID32 | 443 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | ID32 | 321 | 2 | 2 |

**SUPPLY_TBL**

| PARTNER_ID | ITEM_ID | SUPPLY |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID32 | 57 |
| 2 | ID32 | 6 |

**OUTPUT TABLE**

| PARTNER_ID | ITEM_ID | STORE | NEED | NEED_RANK | RECEIVED_SUPPLY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ID32 | 621 | 57 | 1 | 57 |
| 1 | ID32 | 321 | 9 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | ID32 | 315 | 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 1 | ID32 | 732 | 1 | 4 | 0 |
| 2 | ID32 | 443 | 5 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | ID32 | 321 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

Comment: Please include the code you have tried.

Comment: So the codes i have are in SQL and I'm not very familiar on how I can do it on python. On SQL I joined both NEED and SUPPLY tables and created a new table with additional column that compares IF NEED<=SUPPLY THEN ADD the NEED. But it would be really helpful to know how I can do this in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `merge` the dataframes
2. `groupby` and `cumsum` to get the total quantity needed per PARTNER_ID and ITEM_ID.
3. Calculate the quantity supplied and use `clip` to restrict negative values.

```
merged = need_tbl.merge(supply_tbl, on=["PARTNER_ID", "ITEM_ID"], how="left")
total_need = merged.groupby(["PARTNER_ID", "ITEM_ID"])["NEED"].transform("cumsum")
merged["RECEIVED_SUPPLY"] = (merged["NEED"]-(total_need-merged["SUPPLY"]).clip(0)).clip(0)
merged = merged.drop("SUPPLY", axis=1)

>>> merged

   PARTNER_ID ITEM_ID  STORE  NEED  NEED_RANK  RECEIVED_SUPPLY
0           1    ID32    621    57          1               57
1           1    ID32    321     9          2                0
2           1    ID32    315     3          3                0
3           1    ID32    732     1          4                0
4           2    ID32    443     5          1                5
5           2    ID32    321     2          2                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to do so:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
df1 = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table1', conn)
df2 = pd.read_sql('SELECT * FROM table2', conn)

df_final = df1.merge(df2, on = ["PARTNER_ID", "ITEM_ID"], how="left")
```

Comment: Yes I have done that, but I'm not sure how to calculate the RECEIVED_SUPPLY column

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a Python code, but if I could sway you to use `SQL`, here is an attempt using a `window function`

```
with cte as
(select n.*,
        s.supply,
        sum(n.need) over (partition by n.partner_id, n.item_id order by n.need_rank) as cumulative_need
from need n
join supply s on n.partner_id=s.partner_id and s.item_id=n.item_id)

select partner_id,
       item_id,
       store,
       need,
       need_rank,
       case when supply-cumulative_need >=0 then need
            when need+supply-cumulative_need > 0 then need+supply-cumulative_need 
            else 0 
       end as received_supply
from cte      
order by partner_id, item_id, need_rank asc;
```